# Python: Socket not reading byte input

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I'm doing a little localhost socket project in python, I currently only have the thread implementation so multiple clients can connect to the same server. I have a specific message from client to disconnect from server which is `DISSCONECT_MESSAGE = b'0'` when the server recognize the byte zero it should close the connection between the server and the client who sent it. I handle this by using an if statement to catch the byte zero.

The clients **send** function always encode the message to send it to the server, so if user input is `0` it pass through encode and now I have `b'0'`, when server recieve this message it decode it so again I have `0`, thats why in this if statement I encode it again to know if the message is `0`:

```
if msg.encode() == DISSCONECT_MESSAGE:
connected = False
```

I tested `handle_client` by adding a print before the `conn.close ()` function but it never shows that print so it never leaves the while loop and therefore never closes the connection to the client.

Here is my code:

**server.py**

```
import socket
import threading

HEADER = 64
PORT = 65500
SERVER = ''
ADDRESS = (SERVER,PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISSCONECT_MESSAGE = b'0'

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDRESS)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected")

    connected = True

    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg.encode() == DISSCONECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            if msg[:2] == "10":
                conn.send("[CODE 10] Log in request".encode(FORMAT))

            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
            conn.send("Message recived".encode(FORMAT))

    
    print(f"[{addr}] DISSCONNECTED")
    conn.close()



def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept() # Wait to a new connection
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount()-1}")


print("[STARTING] Server is starting...")
start()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket

HEADER = 64
PORT = 65500
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISSCONECT_MESSAGE = b'0'
SERVER = 'localhost'
ADDRESS = (SERVER,PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect(('localhost', 65500))

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(1024).decode(FORMAT))

while True:
    msg = input()
    if msg.encode() == DISSCONECT_MESSAGE:
        print("[DISSCONECTED FROM SERVER]")
        client.send(DISSCONECT_MESSAGE)
    else:
        send(msg)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the return values of `send` and `recv`.  There is no guarantee all bytes were sent (try `sendall`) and and `recv` returns 0 (socket closed) or 1-*length* bytes requested, not necessarily the total number requested.

As far as your main bug, you've sent the character zero ('0') and your server receives it as the length with:

```
msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
```

The result is a length of 0.  `msg` then becomes an empty string with:

```
msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
```

`msg.encode() == b''` (an empty string) not `b'0'` a length 1 string containing a zero character.

Instead, you could abort when you get a length of 0.  Or the normal way to disconnect is to close the connection.  Then the server receives `b''` (a length zero `recv`) which indicates a closed connection.