# Python socket recv is splitting received message

Tags: java, python, sockets, recv

I'm doing a socket communication between a Python and a Java process. I'm trying to send an int with java and receive it in Python.

Java side (sender):

```
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(6666);
        Socket s = ss.accept();

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        
        final int numberToSend = 512;

        dos.writeInt(numberToSend);  //In big endian        
        dos.flush();
```

Python side (receiver):

```
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 6666))

        while True:
            data_received = s.recv(4)
            int_received = int.from_bytes(data_received, byteorder='big')
            print("Received:", data_received, "Number:", int_received)
            
            do_other_stuff(int_received)
```

I'm pretty sure the Java side is working correctly. `dos.size()` gives 4 bytes.

However, from the Python side, it seems `data_received` is being split in two parts. For each cycle, that print gives:

```
Received: b'\x00' Number 0
Received: b'\x00\x02\x00' Number 512
```

The expected would be `Received: b'\x00\x00\x02\x00' Number 512`. With the message split, it's interfering with `do_other_stuff`.
`sys.getsizeof(data_received)` gives 18 and 20 for the first and second parts, respectively.

I've also tried `int_received = struct.unpack("!i", data_received)[0]` but it gives `struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes`, as the messages have 1 and 3 bytes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's unusual to see such small sends split, but that's how stream sockets work. Assuming that you will receive in a single receive exactly the same number of bytes you sent in a single send is a bug, and a common one. You must loop until you receive the expected number of bytes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420075/python-socket-not-receiving-without-sending/43420503#43420503

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are not doing anything logically wrong, but this seems to be the way *TCP* works with it. In [documentation about using sockets](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket), although an amount is expected, the reception is in a loop waiting to get the expected amount of data.

Try doing the same. I.E. in pseudocode:

```
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 6666))

    data_received = b""
    long_received = 0
    while True:
        while long_received < 4:
            data_received += s.recv(4-long_received)
            long_received = len(data_received)
        int_received = int.from_bytes(data_received, byteorder='big') 
        print("Received:", data_received, "Number:", int_received)
        do_other_stuff(int_received)
        data_received = b""
        long_received = 0
```

EDIT: Added annotation from Remy Lebeau. Thank you.

EDIT 2: As user user207421 says, it's TCP's behavior, not Python. Thank you, absolutely new to me. :D

Comment: `data_received += s.recv(4)` needs to be `data_received += s.recv(4-long_received)` instead, otherwise you risk reading too many bytes if there is more data on the socket following the `int`.

Comment: It is the way *TCP* works. Not specific to Python.