# Problem with POST JSON, i got not whole json after receiving

Tags: python, json, sockets, websocket

I have a webparser on the "socket" library (S03) and have a module for parse this dict for unzip needle information(before_json)

code S03

```
# Init .env
env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

#init
secret_token = os.environ['secret_token']

#time
seconds = time.time()
local_time = time.ctime(seconds)

#HDRS
HDRS = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n'
HDRS_404 = 'HTTP/1.1 404 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n'

# create webserver socket
socket_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket_server.bind(('ip', 8888))
socket_server.listen(356)
socket_server.settimeout(5)

#Start procesing incoming json
def start_my_server():
    #def of compare secret key
    def load_secret(secret_token, data):
        try:
            # slack_message_pipe(step=f'I LOAD JSON')
            print('load_secret')
            key = str(data)
            key = re.findall(f'X-Gitlab-Token:...............', key)
            print(key)
            key = str(key).replace("['X-Gitlab-Token: ", '')
            key = str(key).replace("']", '')
            print(key)
            print(secret_token, ' !!! ', key)
            if secret_token == key:
                socket_server.settimeout(None)
                try_to_verification(key)
            else:
                fail_verifivcation()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return
            # slack_message_pipe(step=f'start_my_server.load_secret {e}')

    def try_to_verification(key):
        try:
            print(key, 'key try_to_verification')
            client_socket.send(HDRS.encode('utf-8'))
            client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
            # with open(f"path to file('{local_time}').json", 'w+') as output_file:
            #     json.dump(data, output_file)
            with open(f"path to file", 'w+') as file:
                json.dump(data, file)
                file.close()
            print('next step')
            json_dump_for_proj(data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return
            # slack_message_pipe(step=f'start_my_server.try_to_verification {e}')

    def fail_verifivcation():
        try:
            print('Not find')
            client_socket.send(HDRS_404.encode('utf-8'))
            client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
            addresses = open('ipPOST', 'a')
            addresses.write(str(address) + f'{local_time}\n')
            addresses.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return
            # slack_message_pipe(step=f'start_my_server.fail_verifivcation {e}')

    while True:
        print('start loop')
        try:
            print('try loop')
            while True:
                print('Working...')
                client_socket, address = socket_server.accept()
                print('loop', address)
                data = client_socket.recv(1048576).decode('utf-8')
                # slack_message_pipe(step=f'I GOT JSON')
                load_secret(secret_token, data)
        except Exception as e:
            # slack_message_pipe(step=f'start_my_server.socket.error {e}')
            print(f'pass try {e}')
            fail_verifivcation()
```

code before_json

```
home_path = os.environ['home']

# time
seconds = time.time()
local_time = time.ctime(seconds)


def json_dump_for_proj(data):
    os.chdir(home_path)
    try:
        data = str(data).replace('null', '0')
        # Find head json
        data = re.sub('POST / HTTP/1.1\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n', '', data)
        # data = re.sub(',total_commits_count.*', '}', data)
        data = re.sub('POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n', '', data)
        # data = re.sub('.total_commits_count.*', '}', data)
        data = re.sub('POST.*\r\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n', '', data)
        data = re.sub('"POST / HTTP/1.1\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n', '', data)
        data = re.sub('"POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n', '', data)
        data = re.sub('"POST.*\r\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n', '', data)
        data = json.loads(data)
        # parse needly info
        # Branch
        # print(data['ref'])
        branch = data['ref']
        # print(data['commits'])
        for keys in data['commits']:
            # id
            id_hash = keys['id']
            # author
            # name
            name = keys['author']['name']
            # email
            email = keys['author']['email']
            # files
            # added
            added = keys['added']
            for _ in range(len(added) + 1):
                for j in added:
                    if 'path to file' not in j:
                        added.remove(j)
            # print('path to file' not in added[-1])
            # modif
            modified = keys['modified']
            for _ in range(len(modified) + 1):
                for k in modified:
                    if '' not in k:
                        print(k)
                        modified.remove(k)
            print(id_hash, name, email, branch, modified, sep='\n' + '*' * 100 + '\n')
            list_of = [(name, email), added, modified, id_hash]
            # write_list(list_of)
        # print(not modified and not added)
        message_dict = {"name": name, "email": email, "modified": modified, "added": added}
        if not modified and not added:
            slack_message_pipe_good(
                step=f' \nI got commit by {message_dict.get("name")}\nEmail: {message_dict.get("email")}\n\nBut it is empty, pass')
            return
        try:
            # slack_message_pipe_good(step=f' \nI got commit by {message_dict.get("name")}\nEmail: {message_dict.get("email")}\n\nInside this commit, the following changes\nadded:{message_dict.get("added")}\nmodified:{message_dict.get("modified")}\n\n I am going to the next step')
            git_checkout(id_hash, message_dict)
        except Exception as e:
            slack_message_pipe(step=f'ERROS ON STEP before_deploy_Parse_Json.json_dump_for_proj: {e}')
            return
    except Exception as e:
        with open(f'{local_time}.json',
                  'w+') as data_failure:
            data_failure.write(data)
            data_failure.close()
            slack_message_pipe(step=f' before_deploy_Parse_Json.json_dump_for_proj {e}')


def write_list(list_of):
    try:
        with open(f'path to file', 'w+') as output_file:
            output_file.write(str(list_of) + '\n')
            output_file.close()
            print('I all write')
    except Exception as e:
        slack_message_pipe(step=f' before_deploy_Parse_Json.write_list {e}')


# with open('data.json', 'r') as json_file:
#     data = json.load(json_file)
#     json_dump_for_proj(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Parse_Json')
```

problem:
I got whole json from S03 and after i begining parse him in before_json, but not ussualy it whole, some king of json gone, size of gone block separated\

Comment: did you try to receive the whole json? not really. you just call recv once and it returns some random amount of the json

Comment: @user253751 Not sure understand you, this really receive json, whole json

Comment: @user253751 Could you pls tell me, where did I make a mistake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python socket recv is splitting received message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67726193/python-socket-recv-is-splitting-received-message)

Comment: Or [Receiving end of socket splits data when printed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641840/receiving-end-of-socket-splits-data-when-printed)

Comment: @user253751 Nope, this java, my code on python

Comment: It's the same problem

Comment: @user253751 I don't see way to resolve problem

Comment: keep reading until you get to the end of the json

Comment: @user253751 i recive json from gitlab, i can't separete json in manual

Comment: the next question: how do you know where the end is? The answer: the other computer told you, it's called Content-Length, or there can also be chunked encoding. If you don't want to deal with all this stuff yourself then why are you using sockets instead of the urllib library or the requests library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704

Comment: @user253751 I want, i use socket cause in gitlab webhooks need liisten port on server, i don know how work you exmaple, im begining ride