# How can i get three recieving messages from socket server instead two?

Tags: python, sockets, server, ip, client

Hi guys i cant figure out why socket server sends me second message with the third one at the same time. However I want to get message one by one not together at the same time. How can i do this?
Server code:

```
import socket

host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 5000
ADDR = (host, port) 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                  socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(ADDR)
s.listen()
c, addr = s.accept()  
c.send(b'7:S ACK:4,')
c.send(b'11:S END:kSfdy,')
c.send(b'8:S 120794,')
```

Client code:

```
import socket

HOST = '192.168.1.54'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 5000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
print(s.recv(1024))
print(s.recv(1024))
print(s.recv(1024))    #empty message
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk so there is no need to do that? Socket always send me second message with other N - messages?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I read the page but i dont understand it well. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: @GGGGGG the send calls and the recv calls are ***completely unrelated*** and when you call recv the operating system could give you a random amount of data

Comment: @user253751 random? But when i just call recv function it gives me nothing.

Comment: @GGGGGG because the second call got all the data already and there isn't any left?