# sending the message to multiple clients and receiving the message from multiple clients

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading

I'm trying to send the command from the server to the connected clients and trying to receive the response.

But `connectionList[i].recv(2048)` breaking the while loop. I want the server to ask for the "Enter the command" repeatedly. but the loop is not repeating once it's receiving the response from clients

Here is my code

```
import socket
import sys
from _thread import *
import threading

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Bind the socket to the port
host = socket.gethostname()
server_address = ("0.0.0.0", 8765)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
#Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(5)
print ("Waiting for connection...")

#Variable for the number of connections
numbOfConn = 0
ThreadCount = 0
#Name of list used for connections
addressList = []
connectionList = []

#Function that continuosly searches for connections
def clients(connectionList, addressList):
    
    while True:
            cmd=input("Enter input command:")
            #for loop to send message to each
            for i in range(0,numbOfConn):
                connectionList[i].sendto(str.encode(cmd), addressList[i])
            while True:
                for i in range(0,numbOfConn):
                    response = connectionList[i].recv(2048)
                    #break
                    print("response")
                    if(response.decode('utf-8') =="done"):
                        print("Exiting the loop")
                        break

            

    #connection.close()

while True:
    #accept a connection
    connection, address = sock.accept()
    print ('Got connection from', address)
    
    numbOfConn += 1
    addressList.append((address))
    connectionList.append((connection))

    #Thread that calls the function: clients and stores them in a tuple called connection
    start_new_thread(clients, (connectionList, addressList))
    ThreadCount += 1
    print('Thread Number: ' + str(ThreadCount))


sock.close()
```

could you please help me to find out the issue?

Comment: You are breaking at line 39 from `for` loop, but not from  wrapping `while` loop . Does that sound like a problem ?

Comment: No, even I tried removing that break it's still not repeating the while loop

Comment: It will not work by removing `break`, basically you have to add a break for the while loop around your for. btw, is that `while True:` really required ?

Comment: yes, server will receive the response in batches. so It need to know when to stop expecting for the response

Comment: Not sure why you create a thread for each client. Try just creating one thread and run the server on that thread. Run the input loop on the main thread.

Comment: Also, `sendto` is used on UDP sockets. User `send` for TCP.

Comment: Do not use `send` unless you're checking the return value and prepared to do something if it isn't what you expect. Instead, use `sendall`. But you're entire concept of the way streaming sockets work as illustrated by `connectionList[i].recv(2048)` is flawed. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704) to understand why and how to fix it.