# packets tranfering with sockets get messy with each other

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp, packet

i'm making an online version of MS PAINT in python, and i'm having trouble when i'm trying to transfer the X and Y of the brush to the server.[instead of going one by one, its messy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As9W1.png)

instead of going one by one, its messy

that's how i send:

```
def paint(self, event):
    self.line_width = self.choose_size_button.get()
    paint_color = 'white' if self.eraser_on else self.color
    if self.old_x and self.old_y:
        self.c.create_line(self.old_x, self.old_y, event.x, event.y,
                           width=self.line_width, fill=paint_color,
                           capstyle=ROUND, smooth=TRUE, splinesteps=36)
    self.old_x = event.x
    self.old_y = event.y
    data = (str(self.old_x) + "," + str(self.old_y) + "," + paint_color + "," + str(self.line_width))
    my_socket.send(data.encode())
```

and that's how i recieve in the server:

```
for sock in rlist:
    if sock is listening_socket:
        client_socket, addr = listening_socket.accept()
        open_sockets.append(client_socket)
        print ("opensockets=", open_sockets)
    else:
        data = sock.recv(1024).decode()
        print(data)
        if data == "quit":
            quit_sock(sock)
        else:
            send_xy(data, sock)
```

Comment: if you will take a look on the photo i uploaded("instead of going one by one, its messy") you will see that when i paint slowly, it's sending the cordinates one by one and it's all good. but when i paint faster, the cordinates mix with each other and that's making a big mess. that's my problem.
thanks for your answer

Comment: You make the mistake that seemingly every new python socket programmer makes: you assume that whatever data you send in a single `send()` call will be received in a single `recv()` call. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704) for a better understanding. You will need a proper protocol with message boundaries to do what you want. Also, do not use `send()` unless you're checking the return value and prepared to retry. Use `sendall()` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much :)