# What me need fix in my POST webserver on python?

Tags: python, json, sockets, websocket

I have a script to get json and run it on my ubuntu server with a white ip
I accept json, but not completely, and after this acceptance, the script closes the connection and does not work
I think the problem is that I receive packets incorrectly, but why it does not accept the second packet and why it closes in an infinite loop is not clear to me due to my little experience

```
import os
import socket
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import json


#Init .env
env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
#create webserver socket
def start_my_server():
    socket_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket_server.bind(('ip', port))
    socket_server.listen(32768)
    print('Working...')
    global data
    global HDRS
    while True:
        client_socket, address = socket_server.accept()
        data = client_socket.recv(32768).decode('utf-8')
        # content = 'Well done'.encode('utf-8')
        HDRS = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n'
        # content = load_page_from_get_request(data)
        client_socket.send(HDRS.encode('utf-8'))
        # a = client_socket.send(HDRS.encode('utf-8'))
        # print(a, '+'*20)
        client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
        load_page_from_get_request(32768)
    # print('end')
    # socket_server.close()

def load_page_from_get_request(request_data):
    HDRS = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n'
    HDRS_404 = 'HTTP/1.1 404 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n'
    try:
        with open('data.json', 'w') as output_file:
            json.dump(data, output_file)
        return HDRS.encode('utf-8')
    except EOFError:
        return HDRS_404.encode('utf-8')
    # try

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_my_server()
```

Comment: the argument to `client_socket.recv` should be the number of bytes to receive, NOT the port.  Try using [Websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), I think it will be a better fit for your use case.

Comment: I know this, it is bytes
For link thx, i write this and give callback for

Comment: sorry, i misread your code, I thought you used that same value for `server_socket.bind`

Comment: 1) This doesn't appear to be HTTP 1.1 compliant; 2) your receive loop is very brittle because it relies on incorrect assumptions about `socket.recv()`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704); 3) `load_page_from_get_request(32768)` doesn't make any sense to me, I think you wanted to call `load_page_from_get_request(data)`

Comment: thx mr President, i end my script

Answer (score 0):

The end version of my script

```
import os
import socket
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import json
import datetime


#Init .env
env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
ip = os.environ['ip']
port = os.environ['port']

HDRS = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n'
HDRS_404 = 'HTTP/1.1 404 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n'
#create webserver socket
def start_my_server():
    socket_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket_server.bind((ip, port))
    socket_server.listen(32768)
    print('Working...')
    global data
    while True:
        client_socket, address = socket_server.accept()
        print('loop', address)
        data = client_socket.recv(0).decode('utf-8')
        # content = load_page_from_get_request(data)
        load_page_from_get_request(data)
        client_socket.send(HDRS.encode('utf-8'))
        client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    # print('end')
    # socket_server.close()

def load_page_from_get_request(request_data):
    # HDRS = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n'
    # HDRS_404 = 'HTTP/1.1 404 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n'
    with open(f'data.json{datetime.time}', 'wr') as output_file:
            json.dump(data, output_file)
    return HDRS.encode('utf-8')
    # except EOFError:
    #     return HDRS_404.encode('utf-8')
    # try

print('loop script')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_my_server()
```