# TCP Client error in python SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file TCPClt.py on line 2, but no encoding declared;

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I want to write a python code so that the client will send requests to the server to reverse strings (taken as a command line input) over the network using sockets.
This assignment uses a two-stage communication process. First, in the negotiation stage, the client and the server negotiate through a fixed negotiation port (<n_port>) of the server, a random port (<r_port>) for later use. Then, later in the transaction stage, the client connects to the server through the negotiated random port (<r_port>) for actual data transfer.
When I executed the server code on the Ubuntu server, it worked fine. But when I ran the client code, it gave me "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file TCPClt.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details". Would you please check what is wrong with the Client code and review the whole code so that to perform the job?
Here is the code

## TCP Server

```
import socket
serverPort = 9023
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print("Ther server is ready to receive the connection...")
while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
    ReverseSentence = sentence[::-1]
    connectionSocket.send(ReverseSentence.encode())
    connectionSocket.close()
```

## TCP CLient

```
from socket import *
serverName = ’ubuntu2004-002.student.cs.university.ca’
serverPort = 9023
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))
sentence = raw_input(‘Input lowercase sentence:’)
clientSocket.send(sentence.encode())
modifiedSentence = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print modifiedMessage.decode()
clientSocket.close()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+SyntaxError%3A+Non-ASCII+character -- there's no lack of similar questions.

Comment: All the `send` and `recv` handling is incorrect. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704) for why and how to fix it.