# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in my server

Tags: python, sockets

When I create a server and a clint, I cannot send commands to them
this code server to connect clint

:-

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
h="192.168.1.2"
p=665
s.bind((h, p))
print ("YOUR SESSION HAS BEEN CREATED IN PORT : ", p)
s.listen(1)
v, addr = s.accept()
print("SUCCESS CONECTION ...", addr)
mssge = input ("==> ")
while mssge != 'e':
    v.send(mssge)
    data = v.recv(1024)
    print (data)
    mssge = input ("==> ")
s.close()
```

and i go to deffrant terminal and rin clint code
and this code clint :-

```
import subprocess
import socket

s= socket.socket()
h="192.168.1.2"
p=665
s.connect((h, p))
while True:
        data=s.recv(1024)
        if not data:
                break

        co = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        ct = co.stdout.read() + co.stderr.read()
        cf = str(ct)
        s.send(cf)
s.close()
```

after connect when i right any commend  I have a problem
and this error :-

```
YOUR SESSION HAS BEEN CREATED IN PORT :  665
SUCCESS CONECTION ... ('192.168.1.2', 49508)
==> ls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/i.py", line 13, in <module>
    v.send(mssge)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

please some help

Comment: You have to encode the string first; a `str` value is not a sequence of bytes, but of Unicode code points (not all of which have a single-byte encoding like ASCII; there are millions of possible code points, but only 256 different bytes).

Comment: Eventually you're going to discover that SOCK_STREAM (i.e. TCP) is not a message-oriented protocol and you'll need correct `recv` loop. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704) will explain.

Answer (score 3):

Socket Programming always transfers data in bytes(set of eight 0s and 1s)
When you send, the data you send must be of bytes format.

```
arr = bytes(mssg, 'utf-8')
```

or

```
arr = bytes(mssg, 'ascii')
```

can convert your message to bytes, then send this.

On receiving end, Convert these bytes back to str object with

```
mssg = recieved.decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, `v.send()` requires a bytes-like object, not str, so that input()’s value is a str so that it cannot be. and you can also use this :

`v.send(b”msg” + b” “ * (128 - len(b”msg”)))`

so that if multi-messages can be received because all message len are 64 letters

for receive: `v.recv(64)`

you can also create a function like:

```
def send(msg):
    sendMsg = msg.encode()
    sendMsg += b” “ * (64 - len(sendMsg))
    v.send(msg)
```