# Sockets Python | chatting server multiple clients

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ssl, tls1.3

i am trying to implement a TLS secured socket server in python, and i want multiple clients to connect to the server and talk to each other,

what i would like to do is that each client connecting can receive messages sent by other clients also,

**Server code:**

```
import socket
import threading

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)


def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
            conn.send("Msg received".encode(FORMAT))

    conn.close()


def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")


print("[STARTING] server is starting ...")
start()
```

**Client Code:**

```
import socket

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
SERVER = "192.168.1.141"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)


def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))


send(input('[Send a Message]:  '))


send(DISCONNECT_MESSAGE)
```

where can i add the TLS in this?:/
if something isn't right please inform me :)

---------------------EDIT------------------------------

SERVER:

```
import socket
import select

HEADER_LENGTH = 10
IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 1234

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))
server_socket.listen(5)
sockets_list = [server_socket]
clients = {}


def receive_message(client_socket):
    try:
        message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
        if not len(message_header):
            return False
        message_length = int(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip())
        return {"header": message_header, "data": client_socket.recv(message_length)}
    except:
        return False


while True:
    read_sockets, _, exception_sockets = select.select(
        sockets_list, [], sockets_list)

    for notified_socket in read_sockets:
        if notified_socket == server_socket:
            client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()

            user = receive_message(client_socket)
            if user is False:
                continue
            sockets_list.append(client_socket)
            clients[client_socket] = user

            print(
                f"Accepted new connection from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]} username: {user['data'].decode('utf-8')}")
        else:
            message = receive_message(notified_socket)
            if message is False:
                print(
                    f"closed connection from {clients[notified_socket]['data'].decode('utf-8')}")
                sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)
                del clients[notified_socket]
                continue

            user = clients[notified_socket]

            print(
                f"Received message from {user['data'].decode('utf-8')}: {message['data'].decode('utf-8')}")

            for client_socket in clients:
                if client_socket != notified_socket:
                    client_socket.send(
                        user['header'] + user['data'] + message['header'] + message['data'])

    for notified_socket in exception_sockets:
        sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)
        del clients[notified_socket]
```

CLIENT:

```
from http import client
import socket
import select
import errno
import sys
import threading


HEADER_LENGTH = 10


IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 1234

my_username = input("Username: ")
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((IP, PORT))
client_socket.setblocking(False)

username = my_username.encode('utf-8')
username_header = f"{len(username):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
client_socket.send(username_header + username)


def send_message():
    message = input(f"{my_username} >  ")

    if message:
        message = message.encode('utf-8')
        message_header = f"{len(message):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
        client_socket.send(message_header + message)


while True:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=send_message)
    thread.start()

    try:
        while True:
            # receive things
            username_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            if not len(username_header):
                print("connection closed by the server")
                sys.exit()
            username_length = int(username_header.decode('utf-8').strip())
            username = client_socket.recv(username_length).decode('utf-8')

            message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            message_length = int(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip())
            message = client_socket.recv(message_length).decode('utf-8')

            print(f"{username} > {message}")

    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN and e.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            print('Reading error', str(e))
            sys.exit()
        continue

    except Exception as e:
        print('General error', str(e))
        sys.exit()
```

unfortunately, i cant seem to get the buffer to work right , other clients only receive other clients input when they send messages, so the output is always unordered correctly.

Comment: There seem to be two questions here: (a) how do I write a TLS client/server in Python?, and (2) how do I handle multiple clients? These should be two separate questions. There are many examples available (here and elsewhere) both of writing TLS code in Python *and* of writing chat clients, so you'll want to explain what you've tried and specifically where you're having difficulties.

Comment: `msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)` and lines like it are incorrect. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704) for an explanation.

Comment: hello guys sorry for the confusion i have re-arranged my code and the new code is as follows in the EDIT above