# Problem sending a message using Python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I am trying to finish my simple chat GUI using python and Tkinter and when I run the client file, I get the following error while trying to send a message:

```
PS C:\Users\Nicolas Teixeira\Documents\GitKraken\Simple-GUI-Chat> & "C:/Users/Nicolas Teixeira/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe" "c:/Users/Nicolas Teixeira/Documents/GitKraken/Simple-GUI-Chat/client.py"
Error
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nicolas Teixeira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Nicolas Teixeira\Documents\GitKraken\Simple-GUI-Chat\client.py", line 77, in write
    self.sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

This is my write function:

```
def write(self):
    message = f"{self.nickname}: {self.input_area.get('1.0', 'end')}"
    self.sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    self.input_area.delete('1.0', 'end')
```

I cannot figure out why I keep getting an error.

If it helps, below is the whole source code:

```
import socket
import threading
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext
from tkinter import simpledialog


HOST = '127.0.0.1' 
PORT = 9090


class Client:

    def __init__(self, host, port):

        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((host, port))

        msg = tkinter.Tk()
        msg.withdraw()

        self.nickname = simpledialog.askstring("Nickname", "Please choose a nickname", parent=msg)

        self.gui_done = False
        self.running = True

        gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.gui_loop)
        receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)

        gui_thread.start()
        receive_thread.start()

    def gui_loop(self):
        self.win = tkinter.Tk()
        self.win.configure(bg="lightgray")

        self.chat_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Chat:", bg="lightgray")
        self.chat_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.chat_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.text_area = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.win)
        self.text_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.text_area.config(state='disabled') 

        self.msg_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Message:", bg="lightgray")
        self.msg_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.msg_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.input_area = tkinter.Text(self.win, height=3)
        self.input_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.send_button = tkinter.Button(self.win, text="Send", command=self.write)
        self.send_button.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.send_button.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.gui_done = True

        self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.stop)

        self.win.mainloop()


    def write(self):
        message = f"{self.nickname}: {self.input_area.get('1.0', 'end')}"
        self.sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        self.input_area.delete('1.0', 'end')


    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.win.destroy()
        self.sock.close()
        exit(0)


    def receive(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                message = self.sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if message == 'NICK':
                    self.sock.send(self.nickname.encode('utf-8'))

                else:
                    if self.gui_done:
                        self.text_area.config(state='normal')
                        self.text_area.config('end', message)
                        self.text_area.yview('end')
                        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')
            except ConnectionAbortedError:
                break
            except:
                print('Error')
                self.sock.close()
                break

client = Client(HOST, PORT)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704

Comment: Most probably the server side has closed the socket.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to irc similar to mirc? But where is connect to start?