# Why I don't get body of HTTP request using Python sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to get body of **GET** request made using *socket* module but I am getting only headers even though I set up pretty big buffer size. Web application I reach is made on my own using *Flask*.

sockets.py

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("localhost", 5000))
s.sendall(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:127.0.0.1\r\n\r\n')
print(s.recv(4096).decode('utf-8'))
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('main.html')
```

main.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is what I'm getting executing sockets.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Werkzeug/2.1.2 Python/3.10.5  
Date: Sun, 07 Aug 2022 18:33:53 GMT   
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 66
Connection: close
```

As you can see there is no body of the request. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no guarantee that a single call to `.recv()` will return the entire message, no matter how big the buffer size you pass.  Try calling it again, and see if you get some more data.

Comment: @jasonharper surprisingly, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704