# Why TCP client doesn't wait on receive? And send all the data

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP client and a TCP server. Both of them are supposed to send data in order, I mean the client send then recv, the same for the server first recv and then send.
But I don't know why my TCP client skips ALL THE RECV lines and send all the data instead of waiting for the server response. As far as I read, the sockets are in blocking mode by default
Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**
I've added a minimal reproducible example:

Client side:

```
freq = 8
key = 1
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
sock.connect((self.HOST, self.PORT))
            progress_callback.emit(1)
            sock.sendall(bytes(TcpMsgs.INIT_MSG.value, "UTF-8"))
            str(sock.recv(1024)).strip().lower()
            progress_callback.emit(2)
            sock.sendall(bytes(TcpMsgs.FREQ_MSG.value+str(freq), "UTF-8"))
            str(sock.recv(1024)).strip().lower()
            progress_callback.emit(3)
            sock.sendall(bytes(TcpMsgs.KEY_LEN_MSG.value+str(key), "UTF-8"))
            str(sock.recv(1024)).strip().lower()
            progress_callback.emit(4)
            sock.sendall(bytes(TcpMsgs.BEACON_MSG.value, "UTF-8"))
            str(sock.recv(1024)).strip().lower()
            progress_callback.emit(5)
            #Wait till Bob reply with ok beacon
            str(sock.recv(1024)).strip().lower()
            #analyze msg and return error or ok
            sock.close()
```

Server side:

```
 with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            print("OPENING SOKCET")
            s.bind(("",self.__port))
            s.listen()
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            with conn:
                progress_callback.emit(1)
                print("Connected by:", addr)
                conn.recv(1024)
                progress_callback.emit(2)
                conn.sendall(bytes(" ", "UTF-8"))
                freq = float(str(conn.recv(1024)).split(":")[1])
                progress_callback.emit(3)
                self.__dataDictionary.update({BobVars.FREQ_DICT_KEY.value:freq})
                conn.sendall(bytes("ok","UTF-8"))
                key_len =int(str(conn.recv(1024)).split(":")[1])
                progress_callback.emit(4)
                self.__dataDictionary.update({BobVars.KEY_LEN_DICT_KEY.value:key_len})
                conn.recv(1024)
                progress_callback.emit(5)
                conn.sendall(bytes("ok","UTF-8"))
                #wait beacon ok
                while(self.__waitFlag):
                    pass
                progress_callback.emit(6)
                #Beacon ok
                conn.sendall(bytes("ok","UTF-8"))
                self.__waitFlag = not self.__waitFlag
                rand_array = pickle.dumps([random.randint(0,1) for _ in range(int(key_len))])
                conn.sendall(rand_array)
```

Comment: what does self.__startCommunication do?

Comment: Sorry I'm editing the code right now

Comment: *"why my TCP client skips ALL THE RECV lines and send all the data instead of waiting for the server response"* - what makes you think it does? What you expect the code you show to do, what happens instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704

Comment: Wondering why people think [mcve] means "leave out the imports"?  This definitely isn't reproducible.  "minimal" also means remove unnecessary code, like `progress_callback` (which is also missing and therefore not reproducible).

Comment: What are all of those `recv()` calls returning?

Comment: It doesn't matter if I return something from recv, the code doesn't block in the recv. I expect that my client blocks the code until he receives data maybe I can implement it with while(True)

Comment: Oh, I believe that socket was being created with non blocking mode dunno why. I set it and all works