# Losing Data in TCP socket connectivity

Tags: python, sockets

I am working on socket programming.Here server sends random number of bytes to the machine who connected to server.This random number simulate that server is also receving data from somwhere else and data length can vary much and we are not sure how much.

I am running a server and client both on the same machine. I was expecting no data loss, but to my surprise I can see data loss is happening here too. I must be doing something wrong in my code. I have tried to find but I didn't found anything suspicious. I can just guess the length of data may be a problem, however still I am not sure.

From the server I am first sending the length of the message to the client and then sending the actual message so that I can be sure I have received complete message.

I am connecting to server 100 times and many times the data loss is happening.

Below is my server code:

```
import socket
import struct
import random as rand


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# bind the socket to a specific address and port
server_address = ('localhost', 12345)
sock.bind(server_address)

sock.listen(1)

while True:
    message = "12345" * rand.randint(100000, 200000)
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    message_in_bytes=message.encode()
    length = len(message_in_bytes)
    print(client_address, "connected and message length is ",length)
    length_bytes = struct.pack("<I", length)
    connection.send(length_bytes + message_in_bytes)
    connection.close()
```

Below is client code:

```
import socket
import struct

def connect_server():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ('localhost', 12345)
    sock.connect(server_address)
    message_length_bytes=sock.recv(4)
    length_of_message = struct.unpack("<I",message_length_bytes)[0]
    whole_message=sock.recv(length_of_message)
    sock.close()
    if length_of_message == len(whole_message):
        return "success"
    else:
        return "failed"

stats={'success':0,'failed':0}

for _ in range(100):
    stats[connect_server()] +=1

print(stats)
```

Comment: That's just not how `send()` and [`recv()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) work. For example, `recv(100)` is not guaranteed to return 100 bytes even if the peer sent 1000 bytes. If will return *at most* 100 bytes but not necessarily 100. You need a receive loop to continue to `recv()` bytes objects until all the bytes have been received or EOF/EOS or an error occurs. For more details see [this answer]((https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704)).

Comment: Hi @PresidentJamesK.Polk,Thanks for the response.What I understood is that recv(n) implies the maximum bytes can be received is n and data received may less than n.To get all data I have to keep receiving it until server closes the connection. Have I got that right?

Comment: basically, but it depends on your protocol as to whether the peer closes the connection. In your case the length `n` is sent, so you just need to keep receiving until you've gotten `n` bytes.

Comment: @novice in your case you would want to keep receiving until you received length_of_message bytes in total

Comment: is there any chance even if server have close the connection  after sending all data  the client would still receiving it

Comment: TCP is reliable.  If the server sent the data and closes the connection the client will still receive it as long as the network is up.

Comment: How server then receive acknowledgement if the server would close the connection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`send()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) is not guaranteed to send all the data, limited by the implementation of buffers in the networks stack.  [`recv(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) is also not guaranteed to return *n* bytes.  In both cases check the return value and send/receive the remaining data.

[`sendall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall) is an alternative that will loop and send all the data provided.

For receiving, buffer the data received until a complete message is received.  [`socket.makefile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) is a function that will wrap the socket in a file-like object, where I/O operations like [`read(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read) will return *n* bytes unless the socket is closed, and [`readline()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline) will read until a newline character.

Example:

**server.py**

```py
import socket
import struct
import random as rand

sock = socket.socket()
server_address = ('localhost', 12345)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen()

while True:
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    # closes socket when with is exited
    with connection:
        message = b'12345' * rand.randint(100000, 200000)
        length = len(message)
        print(f'Sending {length}-byte message...')
        length_bytes = struct.pack('<I', length)
        connection.sendall(length_bytes + message) # Use sendall
```

**client.py**

```py
import socket
import struct

def connect_server():
    with socket.socket() as sock:
        server_address = ('localhost', 12345)
        sock.connect(server_address)
        with sock.makefile('rb') as rfile: # wrap in file-like object
            message_length_bytes = rfile.read(4)
            length_of_message = struct.unpack('<I', message_length_bytes)[0]
            whole_message = rfile.read(length_of_message)
            if length_of_message == len(whole_message):
                return 'success'
            else:
                return 'failed'

stats = {'success': 0, 'failed': 0}

for _ in range(100):
    stats[connect_server()] += 1

print(stats)
```

Output (server):

```
Sending 604035-byte message...
Sending 949255-byte message...
Sending 838075-byte message...
 ...
Sending 756820-byte message...
Sending 912215-byte message...
Sending 673175-byte message...
```

Output (client):

```py
{'success': 100, 'failed': 0}
```

Comment: is this buffer common to all I/O devices attached to the machine ? Also I have understood that  socket.makefile() return file like object  and hence able to read data from socket  using read and readline fn. But I am not visualize how this is happening . What if I want to understand it more fundamentally  if possible for you could you please explain it or  requesting to provide me the reference where I can read about it more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @novice The buffers are an implementation detail. Code correctly and you don’t have to worry about the size or implementation. The documentation links to all the functions mentioned are above in the answer.

Comment: I agree with you. But problem is how would I know that my code is correct or my code is compatible with underlying architecture.

Comment: You read and follow the documentation carefully. In your original code, did you check the return values of `send` and `recv`?

Comment: is it good idea to send all bytes at once  in the context server ?

Comment: Please suggest.

Comment: It’s fine as long as you check return values

Answer (score 1):

Then problem is in the sent length.
Your message length may be up to 1 000 000 bytes. It will exceed the length of kernel buffer.
In that case send() return the length actually transferred to buffer and you must re-execute send() for the extra portion.
I did a test on my machine. The length of message was 542610 but send(0 returned 524288 (512KiB).
You must loop on send() until everything is transferred to kernel buffer.

```
rand = rand.randint( 100000,200000)
length_bytes = struct.pack("<I", rand * 5)
whole_message = length_bytes + ('12345' * rand).encode() 
actual_length = 0
while actual_length < len( whole_message:
  nb = send( whole_message[actual_length:])
  actual_length += nb
'''
Note: the length of kernel buffer may be different with your distrib.
```

Comment: Suppose Machine  A is running a server program. When server program calls a send function in order to send a message , all message transferred to kernel buffer and then data is transferred to network. is my understanding right ?

Comment: Yes but the kernel buffer length is limited. If you exceed it, only a portion is transferred to buffer. But on the wire, the packet length is limited to 65535 by the IP header and to approximately 1500 at the Ethernet level (because of the MTU).