Why am I getting a "Connection Refused" Error [Errno 61] in my client-server code?
I'm trying to create a chess game in Python using Sublime Text.
I have a class called Player that first shows a Tkinter entry box to enter your player alias. When the user enters their alias and presses Enter, their alias is saved, the entry box is destroyed, and text is shown saying "waiting for opponent...".
When this message is shown, the player then attempts to connect with the server, so it can send its alias to the server (this is in the function self.establish_connection).
The client and server seem to connect when I run the Python files on the terminal, but not on Sublime Text.
The code is below:
server.py
import threading
import socket

class Server:

    def __init__(self, host='localhost', port=59340):

        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.server.listen(2)

        self.clients = []
        self.aliases = []

    def broadcast(message):

        for client in self.clients:
            client.send(message)

    def handle(self, client):

        while True:

            try:

                message = client.recv(1024)
                self.broadcast(message)

            except:
                index = self.clients.index(client)
                self.clients.remove(client)
                client.close()
                self.broadcast('connection.lost')
                break

    def receive(self):

        while True:

            client, address = self.server.accept()
            client.send('request.alias'.encode('utf-8'))
            print('sent!')
            alias = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            self.clients.append(client)
            self.aliases.append(alias)

            thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,), daemon=True)
            thread.start()


server = Server()
server.receive()

client.py
alias = ''
entered = False


class Player:

    def __init__(self):

        self.host = 'localhost'
        self.port = 59340

        self.gameConfig = [['br', 'bn', 'bb', 'bq', 'bk', 'bb', 'bn', 'br'],
                          ['bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp'],
                          ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
                          ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
                          ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
                          ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
                          ['wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp'],
                          ['wr', 'wn', 'wb', 'wq', 'wk', 'wb', 'wn', 'wr']]

        self.opponent = ''
        self.colour = ''

        self.root = customtkinter.CTk()
        self.root.title('Chess')
        self.root.geometry('600x100+400+400')

                *(create and formats an entry box)*

        self.entry.bind('<Return>', self.clear)
        self.entry.pack(pady=20)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def clear(self, *args):

        if self.entry.get():

            alias = self.entry.get()
            self.entry.destroy()

            time.sleep(0.5)

            self.wait = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.root, text='Waiting for opponent...', font=('Georgia',30))
            self.wait.pack(pady=30)

            self.establish_connection()

    def establish_connection(self):

        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.connect((self.host, self.port))

        while True:

            try:

                message = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                print(message)

                if message == 'request.alias':
                    client.send(alias.encode('utf-8'))

                else:

                    for i in range(2):
                        message = list(zip(*message[::-1]))

                    self.gameConfig = message

            except:

                exit()



Player()

I can't seem to figure out why the client and server are not connecting.
My firewall is already disabled, I've tried to change 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' and empty string '', as well as my actual IP address. All of them gave the same error.
Both the client and server code are running on the same machine.

'Connection refused' means that nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to.

So what can I do? I've tried many different ports and I get the same error message.

Your server has a bare try/except. Maybe you are getting an exception and don’t know it. Add more print statements to trace what is happening.

Your code also makes the common beginner mistake of assuming that the data from one send() call is always returned by one recv call, although the interleaved send and receive pattern may mask that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704.

@user207421 what you describe is only 1 of several different reasons why a "Connection Refused" error can occur. Other reasons can include the server's full backlog is full, and a firewall/router/antivirusmalware blocking the connection.

@RemyLebeau Sure, but not in this case.
